# Flutter: upload small profile image to cloud firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my cloud firestore database I have a collection called users with documents containing the different user profiles. How can I upload a small profile image to one of these documents using flutter? (I'm trying to avoid using firebase storage)

users > 9QfhYAsdcMeE > profileImage: ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe you can directly save an image to cloud firestore. Is there a reason you want to avoid firebase storage?

Comment: I just want to avoid the extra costs and making my app more complicated. As long as the image is less than 1mb I might be able to upload it as a string and convert it into an image in my app

Comment: I definitely get were you are coming from but I think Cloud Storage would be your best option. The overall code shouldn't make your app that much complicated! Maybe just 5-6 more lines of code on your upload function. I can leave an answer of how the code would look if you want!

Comment: You might run into some limitations, and comparing the storage price for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#select-region) with [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), it might not be that much cheaper to avoid using GCS.